# "Ok google" doesn't work

Tags: cyanogenmod, google, ok-google

**Device:** LG G3 F400k
**Rom:** CM12 Nightly (12.1-20151004-NIGHTLY-F400)
**Google App version:** 5.3.23.19.arm
**Google services version:** 8.1.15 (2250156-230)
**Google Play store version:** 5.9.12

---

Everything seems up to date. But I don't have the options to use **Ok Google** on other screens/apps. And the hotword won't even work in the app itself.

*Screenshot:*
[image]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my device as well.

**Device**: SM-G360T
**Android version**: 5.1.1
**Google App version**: 5.13.31.21.arm
**Google services version**: 9.0.83 (234-121911109)
**Google Play store version**: 6.5.08

My solution was to download the [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) (version 1.3.large). It replaces your current launcher, but I thought it was a good exchange. **Warning!** Replacing your current launcher will change your current home screen applications layout, but you can always uninstall Google Now Launcher from the Applications Manager to return to your old launcher.